# How to divide space between elements? Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Lastly I've met with some interesting problem. When I want to precisely divide place on screen between some elements I usually use LinearLayout, put inside my elements and give them some weights. It works great for 2 elements and little more, but when I want to divide screen on more different parts (20 | 60 | 20) and then divide them also, it becomes very frustrating.

How should I do it? I want my layout look the same on different screens, so margin will look different on small and large screen. So for example if I want my button to take 60% of screens width I am forced to add 20% spaces on both sides.

I actually made it using weights, but my xml code looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout
. . .
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="0">


<TextView
    . . .
    android:layout_weight="67"/>

<LinearLayout
    . . .
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="59"
    android:weightSum="0">


    <TextView
        . . .
        android:layout_weight="80"/>

    <ImageView
        . . .
        android:layout_weight="10"/>

    <TextView
        . . .
        android:layout_weight="80"/>



</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    . . .
    android:layout_weight="50"/>

<LinearLayout
    . . .
    android:orientation="horizontal"        
    android:weightSum="0">


    <TextView
        . . .
        android:layout_weight="70"/>

    <LinearLayout
        . . .
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="0">

        <TextView
            . . .
            android:layout_weight="65"/>

        <EditText
            . . .
            android:layout_weight="50"/>

        <TextView
            . . .
            android:layout_weight="75"/>

        <EditText
            . . .
            android:layout_weight="50"/>

        <TextView
            . . .
            android:layout_weight="65"/>


        </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        . . .
        android:layout_weight="70"/>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    . . .
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="0">

    <TextView
        . . .
        android:layout_weight="80"/>

    <LinearLayout
        . . .
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="60">

        <TextView
            . . .
            android:layout_weight="80"/>

        <Button
            . . .              
            android:layout_weight="60"/>

        <TextView
            . . .
            android:layout_weight="50"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        . . .
        android:layout_weight="80"/>



</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    . . .
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="65"
    android:weightSum="0"
    >

    <Button            
        android:layout_weight="1"
        . . ./>

    <Button            
        android:layout_weight="1"
        . . ./>

    <Button            
        android:layout_weight="1"
        . . ./>

</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see there are a lot of empty TextViews which do nothing except taking some place on layout. Is there more intelligent and less frustrating way to precisely divide place on screen between elements?

Glad to hear any advises!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you require nested weights to do the thing you want to do, it would be far more efficient to do this in Java code, in a ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.  Here is an example of how you might do this (also, it only fires once during the initial layout and then removes itself so that you don't have it happening repeatedly for no reason):

Of course, you can replace the Button with another RelativeLayout or LinearLayout to make the view look the way you want, but in the onGloablLayout() method is where you can be ensured that the screen measurements are valid.  This is the place where you can go through and adjust all your nested percentages manually with Java in one layout cycle instead of the exponential performance hit you take when using nested weights.

Let me know if you require additional clarification.

This example is in a Fragment's onCreateView() override, where one would typically find views and style them:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    final View createdView = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    final Button button = (Button) createdView.findViewById(R.id.i_am_button);
    createdView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        public void onGlobalLayout()
        {
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = createdView.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            Log.d(TAG, "Screen Width x Height in Pixels: " + displayMetrics.widthPixels + " x " + displayMetrics.heightPixels);
            button.getLayoutParams().width = 0.60 * displayMetrics.widthPixels;
            button.requestLayout();
            createdView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);  //One-shot!
        }
    });
    return createdView;
}
```

This would assume an XML layout with a Button centered horizontally within a RelativeLayout to work as you have described.

Here is such an example XML snippet for clarity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="150dp"
  android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
  >
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/i_am_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:text="Hello, I am button"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

When using LinearLayout and weights, there are a couple things to keep in mind that are not obvious:

1. Set the LinearLayout's weightSum to the total of the weights you intend to divide amongst
2. If using weights for the width, then all items in the LinearLayout should have their layout_width set to 0 (yes, 0... this is important too)
3. Weights and weightSums do not have to be whole numbers; you can specify a weight of 2.5, for example.

So, to answer your question directly, here is the layout I think you want.  I made a simple horizontal LinearLayout with a blank view on the left and right with a weight of 20%, and then a button in the center that is always 60% weight.  Here is what it looks like on various screen sizes, and below is the XML code:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="100dp"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
  android:weightSum="100.0"
  >
  <View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="20.0"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    />
  <Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="60.0"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:text="Hello, I am button"
    />
  <View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="20.0"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: Here is the updated XML, which has nested weights and is horrible for performance (see comments)... recommended to use RelativeLayout and centering with margins / padding measured in dp to keep a consistent look between screen sizes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="100dp"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
  android:weightSum="100.0"
  >
  <View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="20.0"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    />
  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="60.0"
    android:weightSum="99.9"
    >
    <Button
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="33.3"
      android:text="Hello, I am button1"
      android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
      />
    <Button
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="33.3"
      android:text="Hello, I am button2"
      android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
      />
    <Button
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="33.3"
      android:text="Hello, I am button3"
      android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
      />
  </LinearLayout>
  <View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="20.0"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for a lot of useful information! Could you please clarify one more point. What if we want to divide our middle red space from your example vertically? Is there a way to do all of that avoiding nested weights?

Comment: Not really; this is the exact task that LinearLayout's weight attributes were designed for.  I'm updating the example to have a vertical LinearLayout with 3 buttons inside the red area, each having 1/3 of the height.  It's best to use a simple View for things like this, you can set the background to transparent and its more obvious that the View is doing nothing (instead of a blank TextView, which might confuse someone looking at your code later - including you!)  **However it is important to note that nested weights are bad for performance as it requires exponentially more layout cycles.

Comment: Also, due to the same performance concern mentioned above, the layout preview was unable to render this.  It would probably be more efficient to use a RelativeLayout and figure out some margins or padding measured in dp, and utilize the centering to keep things looking good.

Comment: Is it a good idea to set elements' measures calculated as 1/x part of screen width/height from java code? Then i could count 60% of screen's width and set this value as my button's width. Align that button to the screen's center without any views and weights. But it would be not so clever to count sizes of every element. XML should do that . . .

Comment: Yes, this is a good way to go; a ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayout listener is a good place to do this.  I will create a new answer to your question so we can keep these methods separate.